# How to combine device orientation with bearing to properly rotate an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation, device-orientation

I found [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/) which includes a [great example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/deviceorientationsample.html). What I would like to do differently, however, is to add a bearing for the rotation to focus on.

I've managed to get my current position as follows:

```
var lat = null;
var lng = null;
var intId = null;

function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(7);
    lng = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(7);
    $('#status').html('Latitude: ' + lat + '<br>Longitude: ' + lng);
}
function showError(error) {}

var watchId = null;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var optn = {
        enableHighAccuracy : true,
        timeout : Infinity,
        maximumAge : 0
    };
    watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, showError, optn);

    intId = setInterval(function() {
        if (lat !== null && lng !== null) {
            clearInterval(intId);
        }
    }, 1000);
} else {
    $('#status').html('Geolocation is not supported in your browser.');
}
```

Likewise, I can take my current position along with another fixed postion, and get the bearing with the following functions:

```
function getBearing(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
    var dLon = toRad(lng2-lng1);
    lat1 = toRad(lat1);
    lat2 = toRad(lat2);
    var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
    var rad = Math.atan2(y, x);
    var brng = toDeg(rad);
    return (brng + 360) % 360;
}

function toRad(deg) {
     return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function toDeg(rad) {
    return rad * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Where I am struggling is how to bring the two together (device orientation & bearing)?

Combined with the code from the link above, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jogmc6af/2/). I believe I have all the information I need (gamma, beta, alpha & bearing) but I don't know how to apply them together in `style.transform` so the image points at a specific location rather than north.

Can anyone help me please!?

Comment: where you able to find a solution? For my use case, I just need to rotate an arrow to point towards a destination. I also have the bearing in degrees and an orientation alpha or webkitCompassHeading if available, but not sure how to combine the two.

Comment: @jasan yes and no... I have it working *only* if the page is loaded from a phone in portrait view, and stays in portrait view, but it doesn't work at all in landscape. You can view [the source here](https://imgexp.com/), there is a function called `rotateArrow`. I haven't bothered played with it any further. Please let me know if you make any more progress.